# How to find the longest list in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of lists, the length of the longest list can be found with the following code.

```py
values = [['a','a'], ['a','b','b'], ['a','b','b','a'], ['a','b','c','a']]

longest = 0
for value in values:
    longest = max(longest, len(value))

print(longest)
[out]: 4
```

How can the length of the longest list, or the longest list be found, without a loop.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This will return the longest list in the list `values`:

```
max(values, key=len)
```

Answer (score 6):

This will return the length of the longest list:

```
max(map(len, values))
```

Answer (score 2):

- The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022524) from [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing) is great for finding the **first**, longest sub-list, and it's fast.

  - For a list of 1M lists, varying in length from 1-15, it takes 29.6 ms to return the first list with the maximum length.

```py
values = [['a','a'], ['a','b','b'], ['a','b','b','a'], ['a','b','c','a']]

max(values, key=len)

[out]:
['a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
```

- This `pandas` solution isn't a competitor with the accepted answer for speed in returning the first, longest list.
- There are a lot of people using `pandas` for analysis, so this is a valid question, from that perspecive.
- This solution is for returning **all** sub-lists for the max list length, or a specified length.

  - `df.len.max()` can be substituted with an `int`, to return lists of a specified length.
- This solution takes advantage of [pandas: Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).
- This solution is slower, but it's returning a different result

  - The lists have to be loaded in pandas
  - The `'len'` column is created
  - The Boolean mask is used to return all the matching lists
  - For a list of 1M lists, varying in length from 1-15, it takes 682 ms to return all the lists with the maximum (or specified) length.
- It should be noted, `max(df.lists, key=len)` can be used on a `pandas.Series` to find the first, longest list.

```py
import pandas as pd

# convert the list of lists to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'lists': values})

# display(df)
          lists
0        [a, a]
1     [a, b, b]
2  [a, b, b, a]
3  [a, b, c, a]

# create column for the length of each list
df['len'] = df.lists.map(len)

          lists  len
0        [a, a]    2
1     [a, b, b]    3
2  [a, b, b, a]    4
3  [a, b, c, a]    4

# select lists with max(len)
max_len = df[df.len == df.len.max()]  # or [df.len == some int] for a specific length

# display(max_len)
          lists  len
2  [a, b, b, a]    4
3  [a, b, c, a]    4
```

### `%timeit`

```py
import pandas as pd
import random
import string

# 1M sub-list of 1-15 characters
l = [random.sample(string.ascii_letters, random.randint(1, 15)) for _ in range(10**6)]

%timeit max(l, key=len)
29.6 ms ± 1.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# function to do all the pandas stuff for testing
def get_max_len(l):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'lists': l})
    df['len'] = df.lists.map(len)
    return df[df.len == df.len.max()]


%timeit get_max_len(l)
682 ms ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```