# finding list with most elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, element

Here are 3 lists:

```
test1 = ['a','a','a','a','a']
test2 = ['b','b,'b']
test3 = ['c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c']
```

How can I output the list with most elements? This solution below is from @Rifat Alptekin Çetin:[Python: How do I find the list with the most elements in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806658) but this outputs a 'string' defined by dictionary. How do I output the list with most elements?

```
lists=[test1, test2, test3]
listnames=["list1", "list2", "list3"]

most = listnames[np.argmax([len(l) for l in lists])]
```

**Current output**

```
most = 'list3'
```

**Desired output**

```
most = test3
```

Comment: The list with most elements that are the same or just the longest list?

Comment: What Python function would you use to decide which list has the most elements? (hint: it's `len`) Also, do you need to know what variable has the longest list, or are you just interested in the longest itself? What do you need it for?

Comment: I'm looking for list with most elements irrespective of similar elements @KentShikama.

Comment: _but this outputs a 'string' defined by dictionary._ What do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to find longest list in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022499/best-way-to-find-longest-list-in-list)

Comment: Yes you are right @AMC I couldnt find your example - for some reason didnt show up. Rifat previous solution looks like a dictionary but I may be wrong: he assigns string (key) for each element (value) then loops through list to output string (key). Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> test1 = ['a','a','a','a','a']
>>> test2 = ['b', 'b', 'b']
>>> test3 = ['c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c']
>>> lists = [test1, test2, test3]
>>> max(lists, key=len)
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

This gives you the actual list and not the string name you were talking about

```
>>> assert max(lists, key=len) == test3
>>>
```

Comment: @izzleee `max(lists, key=len)` will return that list

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the longest list using list-comprehension:

```
most = [x for x in [test1,test2,test3] if len(x) == max([len(y) for y in [test1,test2,test3]])][0]
```

Basically, it makes a list of the lists's lengths, picks the biggest, then chooses the first of the lists with that length.